# Angular 5 Filter custom Filter Predicate

Tags: angular, angular-filters

I'm trying to filter records by multiple columns, getting some errors while type something inside filter input box.

Getting below error when type something in InputBox.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
>       at MatTableDataSource.myFilterPredicate [as filterPredicate] (numbers.component.ts:191)
>       at eval (table.es5.js:551)
>       at Array.filter ()
>       at MatTableDataSource._filterData (table.es5.js:551)
>       at MapSubscriber.eval [as project] (table.es5.js:512)
>       at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:79)
>       at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:95)
>       at CombineLatestSubscriber.notifyNext (combineLatest.js:133)
>       at InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:25)
>       at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:95)

Comment: Can you provide the respective code of numbers.component.ts - seems like a reference issue since it's 'undefined'..

Comment: @iLuvLogix , thanks for quick replay , please have a look into respective code

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies here:

```
 data.NUMBERRANGEEND.toString().trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.NUMBERRANGEEND.toLowerCase()) !== -1
```

`toString()` expects an argument in front - so you need to debug your `data.NUMBERRANGEEND` since it seems it's not containing any integer to be converted.

To determine where things went wrong you could debug the object-properties in the backend when they get processed/before they get sent to/requested from the frontend..

Comment: Your are absolutely right getting errors for - data.NUMBERRANGEEND but this property getting string value only from back-end

Comment: So why don't you debug the object properties when you receive it from the backend or process them in the backend with a couple of console.logs to determine where things went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem.  **Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined at MatTableDataSource.myFilterPredicate [as filterPredicate]**  This means you might have another column in your mat table that is completely empty and that's why it can't read empty string. 
Solution: try to add some values in the empty column or define a condition that says; if column is empty then don't treat it as null (treat it like an " " string).